# Hadoop lzo single split after index

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, lzo, hadoop-lzo

I have a LZO compressed file `/data/mydata.lzo` and want to run this though some MapReduce code I have. I first create an index file using the [hadoop-lzo](https://github.com/twitter/hadoop-lzo) package with the following command:

```
>> hadoop jar hadoop-lzo-0.4.21.jar \
    com.hadoop.compression.lzo.DistributedLzoIndexer \
    /data/mydata.lzo
```

This runs successfully

```
17/01/04 11:06:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1472572940387_17794
17/01/04 11:06:41 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1472572940387_17794 running in uber mode : false
17/01/04 11:06:41 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/01/04 11:06:52 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 86% reduce 0%
17/01/04 11:06:54 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
17/01/04 11:06:54 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1472572940387_17794 completed successfully
```

and creates the file `/data/mydata.lzo.index`. I now want to run this through some other Hadoop Java code

```
hadoop jar myjar.jar -input /data/mydata.lzo
```

It executes correctly but takes FOREVER. I noticed it only splits the file once (when I run this same job over non-LZO files it splits it about 25 times)

```
mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
```

What am I doing wrong?

The hadoop-lzo documentation is a little lacking. It says "*Now run any job, say wordcount, over the new file*". I first thought I should use the `/data/mydata.lzo.index` file as my input but I get an empty output when using that. The documentation also says "*Note that if you forget to index an .lzo file, the job will work but will process the entire file in a single split, which will be less efficient.*" So for whatever reason it is not seeing the `index` file.

What is the proper way to pass the index file?

**EDIT**: According to [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/twitter/hadoop-lzo/issues/125) the index file is automatically inferred and will split according to the file size. Still not sure why I am getting a single split.

Comment: what is the size of the original file ? And after compression  ?  I hope your file size is bigger than the "min split size" property

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
hadoop jar myjar.jar -input /data/mydata.lzo -input /data/mydata.lzo.index
```